# Is it possible to get a reference to a specific instance of a COM component?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, desktop-application

I have an application that I interact with using VB.NET code through a COM Interface. This all works fine as long as I only have one instance of the application running. However, if I have 2 instances of the application running there is no way to pick which one I get when I initialize the connection using Interaction.GetObject(). I am currently calling this method like this; only defining the class that I want to get ('XXX' is my application name):

`var = Interaction.GetObject(, "XXX.application")`

I have spent a bit of time researching the Component Object Model (COM) but have gotten a little overwhelmed by the amount of information. I am hesitant to spend a bunch of time learning the ins-and-outs of the entire COM service only to learn that this is a permanent limitation and I have wasted my time. Is this worth my time to investigate further? Is this something that is actually able to be solved with more hard work on my end or is this a permanent limitation with Windows?

**Relevant Help Documentation:**

Component Object Model (COM):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal

*Interaction.GetObject(String, String) Method:*  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.getobject?view=net-7.0

Through reading the COM documentation I found that the running COM objects are stored in the Running Object Table (ROT). I then searched through others code online relating to the ROT and I re-wrote it and tried to simplify it to make it as easy to follow as possible. I also fully commented it to make sure that I understood how every piece of it was working. The code runs through just as expected. It returns the the same number of COM object references as the number of application instances as it should.

However, every one of the returned COM reference instances seems to point to a single instance of the application. When sending a command to any of the returned COM reference instances, they all effect the same instance of the application. Am I missing something here?

Here is the code I re-wrote/commented:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes

Public Class RunningObjectTableInterface

    'Returns a pointer to an implementation of IBindCtx (a bind context object). This object stores information about a particular moniker-binding operation.
    Private Declare Function CreateBindCtx Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal reserved As UInteger, <Out> ByRef ppbc As IBindCtx) As Integer
    
    'Returns a pointer To the IRunningObjectTable Interface On the local running Object table (ROT).
    Private Declare Sub GetRunningObjectTable Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal reserved As Integer, <Out> ByRef prot As IRunningObjectTable)
    
    Public Const S_OK As Integer = 0
    
    Public Shared Sub TestROT()
        Dim progIds As String() = {"XXX.Application"}
        Dim retInstances As List(Of Object) = GetRunningInstances(progIds)
    
        For Each comInstance As Object In retInstances
            'Interact with each of the returned COM Objects here
        Next
    End Sub
    
    'Get all running instance of the input progIds by querying ROT
    Public Shared Function GetRunningInstances(ByVal progIds As String()) As List(Of Object)
        Dim clsIds As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    
        'Get the clsIds for each of the programIds that were passed in
        For Each progId As String In progIds
            Dim type As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId)
            If type IsNot Nothing Then
                clsIds.Add(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper())
            End If
        Next
    
        'Get Running Object Table ...
        Dim ROT As IRunningObjectTable = Nothing
        Call GetRunningObjectTable(0, ROT)
    
        If ROT Is Nothing Then 'Error handle GetRunningObjectTable for nothing returned
            Throw New Exception("GetRunningObjectTable did not return a value.")
            Return Nothing
        End If
    
        'Get enumerator for all entries in ROT
        Dim monikerEnumerator As IEnumMoniker = Nothing
        ROT.EnumRunning(monikerEnumerator)
    
        If monikerEnumerator Is Nothing Then 'Error handle EnumRunning for nothing returned
            Throw New Exception("EnumRunning on the ROT did not return values.")
            Return Nothing
        End If
    
    
        'Create a list of items to return
        Dim retInstances As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
    
    
        Dim monikers As IMoniker() = New IMoniker(0) {} 'Create an object to hold the item returned from the monikerEnumerator
        monikerEnumerator.Reset() 'Reset the enumeration sequence to the beginning.
    
        'Loop through each moniker and see if it is the requested type
        While monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, Nothing) = S_OK
    
            'Create a IBindCtx object to use in GetDisplayName
            Dim bindCtx As IBindCtx = Nothing
            CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx)
    
            If bindCtx Is Nothing Then 'Error handle CreateBindCtx for nothing returned
                Continue While
            End If
    
            'Get the display name of this moniker
            Dim displayName As String = ""
            monikers(0).GetDisplayName(bindCtx, Nothing, displayName)
    
            'Loop through each clsId to see if the display name of the current moniker is equal
            For Each clsId As String In clsIds
                If displayName.ToUpper().Contains(clsId) Then 'The display name is equal to one of the clsIds
    
                    'Get the object associated with this moniker
                    Dim ComObject As Object = Nothing
                    ROT.GetObject(monikers(0), ComObject)
    
                    If ComObject IsNot Nothing Then 'Error handle GetObject for nothing returned
                        retInstances.Add(ComObject) 'Add COMObject to the return list
                        Exit For 'Exit loop and check the next moniker
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End While
    
        Return retInstances
    End Function

End Class
```